# Variable dependent flux boundary condition in fipy

Tags: python, finite-element-analysis, fipy

I have a case where reaction flux is present at a boundary and flux is proportional to the concentration variable `c`. Will the following correctly apply the boundary condition:

```
c.faceGrad.constrain(k*c.faceValue, mesh.physicalFaces["ReactingFace"]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a [Robin Condition](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/USAGE.html#applying-robin-boundary-conditions). Please revise your question if that documentation doesn't help.